# Expectation of a Matrix Raised to a Power

Tags: expected-value, matrix-inverse, random-matrix

I have been able to find little literature related to the topic online (e.g., [A note on the Expected Value of an Inverse Matrix](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Theodore_Groves/publication/31400997_A_Note_on_the_Expected_Value_of_an_Inverse_Matrix/links/02bfe511db35022767000000/A-Note-on-the-Expected-Value-of-an-Inverse-Matrix.pdf) such that E($\frac{1}{X})$ $\geq$ ($\frac{1}{E(X)}$), though, vaguely, I am working on a project in which an inequality for expectations of matrices with powers other than the inverse might come in handy.

While my search led me to a particular paper which had seemingly solved this problem, it had apparently been redacted (see: [Editor's Note: A Note on the Expected Values of Powers of a Matrix](http://www.jstor.org.uml.idm.oclc.org/stable/3314700)). Has anyone come across any useful literature on the topic of random matrix powers?